# Need to connect ADF and BigQuery through IR

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-data-factory

I want to connect Azure data factory and Google Big query through IR, what are the values required and how can I access the data from Big Query

Answer (score 2):

ADF supports google big query connector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery. An linkedsevice payload example is given below:

```html
{
    "name": "GoogleBigQueryLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "GoogleBigQuery",
        "typeProperties": {
            "project" : "<project ID>",
            "additionalProjects" : "<additional project IDs>",
            "requestGoogleDriveScope" : true,
            "authenticationType" : "UserAuthentication",
            "clientId": "<id of the application used to generate the refresh token>",
            "clientSecret": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value":"<secret of the application used to generate the refresh token>"
            },
            "refreshToken": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "<refresh token>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```